# KnockoutJS 2 and $ bindings don't work anymore

Tags: knockout.js

I've upgraded to `KnockoutJs 2` and found that pages that use template bindings have stopped working.

I have a template binding which uses `${ x }` bindings, but these aren't being resolved.

I removed the template and used the new control flow bindings, but it still didn't work. I had to convert to using data-bind instead.

I don't really want to convert everything over, I want it to be backward compatible with `jquery` templates as well as give me the possibility of using the new control flow bindings.

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Do you still have a reference to the jQuery tmpl library? I am using KO2 and tmpl together fine. Make sure you aren't using a bit of knockout's native template syntax along with tmpl syntax as I have found this to cause problems in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery templates, Knockout 2.0 requires a specific version of it. See the note here from Knockout's page: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/

Steve Sanderson mentions ...

> As mentioned under “backward compatibility notes”, if you are using
>   jQuery Templates, you’ll need to update it to 1.0.0pre as found at
>   https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

- Note that KO 1.3beta ended up being released as KO 2.0.0

If you did not intend to use jQuery templates, please post a jsFiddle of your code and we can help you resolve it.

[UPDATE]
In a further comment you asked about how to do templates. Here are 2 possibilities taken from examples on the Knockouts site http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) that use native templates for KO 2.0.0

```
<h2>Participants</h2>
Here are the participants:
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', foreach: people }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>

 function MyViewModel() {
     this.people = [
         { name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 },
         { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 }
     ]
 }
 ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

This gives the same result as embedding an anonymous template directly inside the element to which you use foreach, i.e.:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: people">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Perhapd you know how to use native `KO2` templates when binding an array of strings objects, s I've not named fields so how I can access in the `data-bind="...???"` binding expression? So I'm doing `foreach: names` where names - array of strings, how to bind each string in the template body? Also `$parent/$root` quite helpful, how to access parent ViewModel using native binding?

Comment: @sll - I just saw your comment. When looping through the string array you can use $data to get to the current item, which is each name in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the jquery.tmpl stuff. It's a dead-in-the-water project that will not be developed further. The "${ x }" stuff is jquery.tmpl

Knockout 2.0 now uses it's own native template library. Use that. It's not backwards compatible with "${ x }", but that's why Knockout changed to a major version upgrade (1.2 to 2.0) -- there are breaking changes.

Comment: OK, I think I might actually take this route going forward. Does this mean that all ${ } have to be changed to regular data-bind expressions?

Comment: If you remove jQuery templates, then yes. In that case you would use native templates. I edited my answer above to show 2 examples of native templates and a link to the docs.

Comment: Perhapd you know how to use native `KO2` templates when binding an array of strings objects, s I've not named fields so how I can access in the `data-bind="...???"` binding expression? So I'm doing `foreach: names` where names - array of strings, how to bind each string in the template body? Also `$parent/$root` quite helpful, how to access parent ViewModel using native binding?

Comment: @sll That should really be posted as a question of its own, but the short answer is to use $data to access the individual strings.